# Permutations of input and run external program in loop

Tags: python, data-science

I am trying to write a file for input to another program which contains permutations of a list of user given inputs. I have a semi-okay understanding of Python but this has (currently) beaten me.

The input file will contain a few lines of default text followed by a number of user given inputs. The number of user inputs will be defined by the user. Here is an example of how I want it to go (stuff after : is typed by user):

```
How many data sets?: 3

Data set 1: /here/is/data

Data set 2: /here/is/other/data

Data set 3: /here/is/last/data
```

Then this is the file written out initially:

```
some text predefined
some more of the predefined
this is more
INPUT_FILE=/here/is/data
```

Then a program is run using this files as input (currently doing this using subprocess). When the program has run, the output is written to a file and then the original input file is altered to the next in the sequence of permutations from the input eg:

```
some text predefined
some more of the predefined
this is more
INPUT_FILE=/here/is/data
INPUT_FILE=/here/is/other/data
```

Then the program is run again using this altered file as input and the output is appended to the file containing the output from the previous program run. This would then loop for all permutations of the three inputs. I would like this to work no matter how many inputs were given.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! This is a good description of a general problem, but as stack overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service, we ask that you include a [mcve] including code for what you've already tried, and a _specific_ problem that you are seeking guidance or help on. In other words, your problem describes several individual steps you are trying to accomplish, but you haven't stated which step you are having difficulty with.

Comment: Apologies, will amend with the specific problem.